# The icons in my Dock is locked

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks, dock

Some time ago I locked my Dock, because I was annoyed by accidently dragging the icons around in the Dock.

I did that by running this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock contents-immutable -bool true; killall Dock;
```

Now I want to rearrange some icons, therefor I want to disable it again. I have tried to do so by running this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock contents-immutable -bool false; killall Dock;
```

But it does not work and I have tried to reboot afterwards, but the Dock is still locked.

I have checked the com.apple.dock.plist file and the value for contents-immutable is set to NO.

My user is the admin user of the Mac, so that shouldn't be the problem.

I am running OS X 10.9.3.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I simply forgot how to move the icons. I thought I should click and hold, wait until the menu appeared and then drag. That wasn't the way to do it.

I found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3817000) and it turns out that you should Click, hold and drag before the menu appears.